# Paging filtered data in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm not terribly familiar with SQL. As such, I have a SQL script that filters data in my table:

```
SELECT X, Y, Z FROM dbo.a 
WHERE Y LIKE '%Test%' AND Z >= 5 AND Z <= 10
```

Now I'm trying to add paging to this. I'm using MS SQL Server 2008. The script I'm using for paging is this:

```
SELECT X, Y, Z
FROM (
SELECT X, Y, Z, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY X) AS RowNum
FROM dbo.a ) AS A
WHERE A.RowNum BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

How would I combine these so that it grabs a specific page of data from my filtered table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your subquery should be the one with the predicates.

Paging in data is a combination of offset and page-size. Offset is the desired page index multiplied by the page-size. So if your page is 20 results and you want page 5, then the rownumber range is from `(5-1) * 20` to `5 * 20` (we subtract 1 from the page-number because we want a 0-based index).

In your case, the query would be this:

```
SELECT
    X, Y, Z
FROM (
    SELECT
        X, Y, Z,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY X) AS RowNum
    FROM
        dbo.a 
    WHERE
        Y LIKE '%Test%'
        AND
        Z >= 5
        AND
        Z <= 10
 ) AS A
 WHERE
     A.RowNum BETWEEN @pageIndex * @pageSize AND (@pageIndex + 1) * @pageSize
```

...where `@pageIndex` is the 0-based page number (so subtract 1 from the cardinal page number).

Comment: Awesome. I'll give this a try.